# How to use one Material Autocomplete input for two values in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, autocomplete, angular-material

Trying to create a search with Material's autocomplete that can filter by both user name or user ID. I have it somewhat working in [this Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-u9acxd?file=src/app/users/users.component.html).

If you mouse click a user name in the autocomplete options, you go to the user detail page as expected. However, if you use the keyboard arrows to select and submit with 'Enter', it shows [object Object] in the input instead of the Name. How would I go about showing the user name instead?

Also, is there a way for the auto complete to list ID's instead of names if the user inputs numeric values?

**HTML:**

```
<p>Search Users by Name or ID</p>
<form [formGroup]="searchForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <input type="text" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="searchControl" />
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option (click)="onSubmit()" *ngFor="let option of (filteredOptions | async)" [value]="option">
      {{ option.name }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
  <input type="submit" style="display: none;">
</form>
```

**TS:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { map, startWith } from "rxjs/operators";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from "@angular/forms";
import { User } from "../user";
import { UserService } from "../user.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-users",
  templateUrl: "./users.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./users.component.css"]
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
  filteredOptions: Observable<User[]>;
  users: User[] = [];
  options: User[];
  searchControl = new FormControl();
  searchForm = new FormGroup({
    searchControl: this.searchControl
  });

  getUsers(): void {
    this.users = this.UserService.getUsers();
  }

  constructor(public router: Router, private UserService: UserService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUsers();

    this.options = this.users;

    this.filteredOptions = this.searchControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(""),
      map(value => this._filter(value))
    );
  }

  private _filter(value: string): User[] {
    const filterValue = value;
    return this.options.filter(
      option =>
        String(option.id)
          .toLowerCase()
          .indexOf(filterValue) > -1 ||
        option.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) > -1
    );
  }

  // Search bar
  onSubmit() {
    let userId = this.searchControl.value.id;
    this.router.navigate(["user-details", userId]);
  }
}
```

Comment: so on user select's value using UP/DOWN arrow, do you want to show text instead of [object Object]? like `Barri Lebbon`

Comment: please check and confirm below answer if it worked

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use [`displayWith`](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview#setting-separate-control-and-display-values) property of AutoComplete, so the code change required is:

HTML:

```
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFunction">
    <mat-option (click)="onSubmit()" *ngFor="let option of (filteredOptions | async)" [value]="option">
      {{ option.name }}
    </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

In TS:

```
displayFunction(user: User): string {
    return user && user.name ? user.name : "";
}
```

[StackBlitz_Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bqukxj?file=src/app/users/users.component.ts)